# How to delete just the entity and its join record in a many-to-many Hibernate association

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I have a serious issue with a many-to-may relationship. I only mapped the relationship on the side of the group as follows

```
<class mutable="true" name="entities.Group" table="StudGroup">
 ...
 <set lazy="false" cascade="save-update" name="studentSet" table="stud_group_join">
<key column="groupId"/>
<many-to-many class="entities.Student" column="studId"/>
</set>
...
</class>
```

By deletion attempts I experience the following:

1. By deleting a group, the group and all the students associated with
   it are deleted.
2. By attempting to delete a student, I recieve an Exception:

   ```
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
     Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`students`.`stud_group_join`,
     CONSTRAINT `FK30E5217826CEA4E5` FOREIGN KEY (`studId`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`))
   ```

I would like my program to only delete the entity I passed to and the join record, bound to it.

Any help of yours I will appreciate.

Comment: Please let me correct my question: deleting the group works correctly, now I see it. However the Exception is still thrown when deleting a student and I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to do it by yourself: find all the groups containing that student, remove the student from all these groups, then delete the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete a `Student` you'll have to do it like this:

```
student.getGroups().remove(student);
entityManager.remove(student);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see your suggestion is the right way, in spite that the relation between the groups and the students, as I mentioned, is only realized by the Group in the model, so I don't have a "student.groups" filed, just a "group.studentSet". But I completely understand and accept what you say. I must confess I had already thought about this way of solution too before I asked, I was just not sure about its elegance. So I'm primarily thakful to you for making me sure. :-)